# How can I install the "third party" software option after I've skipped it in the installer?

Tags: installation

I did not select []install this third-party software when installing 13.04.

Is there a way I can get those software items? Install over existing?

(I may be missing something to get Spring STS to be able to open/launch.)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Open a terminal on the Dash and type:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Enter your password and all third-party programs that you need to be installed. With this packages you will get also some extras like Microsoft fonts.

If you need proprietary drivers, go to System Settings -> Software & Updates and choose the hive "Additional drivers".

Comment: Ok. I appreciate the knowledge. Hopefully it will not slow my start-up / re-booting down. But you did provide an answer to my question.

Comment: So, actually I may need the 'Wine' program to open a .exe? Is that included in the ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: This third-party only include drivers and software a normal users require. Wine won't be in that.