# My Ubuntu Linux 20.4 WIFI makes all my computers disconnect from network

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

My Laptop using Ubuntu 20.4 when I connect to WIFI it connects and disconnects very often and when it occurs all other computers disconnects. I'm using a Realtek Wifi Adapter.

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel driver in use: rtw_8822ce
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8822ce
```

My power-safe wifi is set to 2 from 3 `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

I don't know why this happens. as soon my linux laptops starts WIFI goes down across all devices and have intermittent connections.

Comment: Could it be duplicate IP addresses? Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: There is no Ubuntu version 20.4 there is a version 20.04

Comment: I added more channels to my router and seems to work fine. 10 exacly

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu doesn't come with drivers, and pre-installed drivers are buggy at least for some laptops.

Enable third party driver option.

Steps:

1. Open "Additional drivers" app
2. Check additional drivers tab
3. You can find your wireless device, make sure to select an option if it says "do not use this driver". In my case using dkms driver fixed the issue.

[image]

Note: if you don't see additional drivers, make sure to check this also. [Install thirdparty software ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290293/how-can-i-install-the-third-party-software-option-after-ive-skipped-it-in-the)